# Parallel texts !You can't use `\lastbox' in vertical mode!

Tags: parallel-texts

There is an error about closing `\Columns` in a parallel-text setting, and I can't understand what is causing it.

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
%% Additional note from LLT: you don't need fontspec or xelatex for reledmac or reledpar to work. However, if your document _does_ involve different languages with different scripts/fonts (e.g. English and Greek or Arabic etc), then it's a good idea to use those packages -- see https://www.overleaf.com/read/wfdxqhcyyjxz for an example
%
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian, french]{babel}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1.5in, top=1in]{geometry} %, showframe]
\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}

\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.3\textwidth}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}

\usepackage{comment}        

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{1ex}

\setgoalfraction{0.8}
\numberlinefalse
\begin{document}   
\begin{sloppypar}

\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
    \selectlanguage{russian}
      \beginnumbering

        \pstart[
        \chapter*{\foreignlanguage{russian}{ИСТОРИЯ ПЕРВАЯ}}
        \section*{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Суета Вокруг Дивана}}]
        \pend
        \pstart
        Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. Бессмыссленный текст. 
        \pend
      \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
    \selectlanguage{english}
      \beginnumbering

        \pstart[
        \chapter*{THE FIRST TALE}
        \section*{Run Around a Sofa}]
        \pend
        \pstart
        Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. Dummy text. 
        \pend

     \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pairs} 
\Columns
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

> Line 58. You can't use `\lastbox' in vertical mode. \Columns

Comment: Don't use only chapter/section. Add some dummy text.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Done, error remains the same

Answer (score 1):

If I add some dummy text after the optional arguments of \pstart it works fine for me:

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
%% Additional note from LLT: you don't need fontspec or xelatex for reledmac or reledpar to work. However, if your document _does_ involve different languages with different scripts/fonts (e.g. English and Greek or Arabic etc), then it's a good idea to use those packages -- see https://www.overleaf.com/read/wfdxqhcyyjxz for an example
%
\usepackage[T2A, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian, french]{babel}
%\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1.5in, top=1in]{geometry} %, showframe]
\usepackage[series={},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}

\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.3\textwidth}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{1ex}

\setgoalfraction{0.8}
\numberlinefalse
\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}

\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
    \selectlanguage{russian}
      \beginnumbering

        \pstart[
        \chapter*{\foreignlanguage{russian}{ИСТОРИЯ ПЕРВАЯ}}
        \section*{\foreignlanguage{russian}{Суета Вокруг Дивана}}]
        sss
        \pend

      \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
    \selectlanguage{english}
      \beginnumbering

        \pstart[
        \chapter*{THE FIRST TALE}
        \section*{Run Around a Sofa}]
        sss
        \pend

     \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
\end{pairs}
\Columns
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed it works. It's a shame that I can't put anything but a title in the first chunk due to some limitations of reledpar formatting. Will try to think about how to avoid it.